# ¿Como realizar multiples reportes en C#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Amigos

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy desarrollando un sistema para una empresa y estoy en la etapa de programar los reportes.

La empresa para la que trabajo al final del día saca muchos reportes (cantidad de efectivo para cuadrar ventas, mercaderías por vencer, control de stock, etc.), el problema es que estos reportes deben ir impresos en conjunto, es decir si imprimo uno deben imprimirse todos. Estoy usando Crystal Reports por requerimientos de la empresa, pero no se como adaptar esto a la programación, e intentado con sub-reportes pero no funciona del todo bien, usar varias ventanas no es opción ya que si por olvido alguno de los usuarios no saca el reporte es un problema, ademas de poder hacerle la vida un poco mas fácil.

Existe alguna forma de adaptar varios crystal reports (archivos .rpt) independientes en una sola ventana?, o alguna forma de imprimir varios reportes de una sola vez?

Cualquier sugerencia me serviría. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Es bastante tedioso, pero puede hacerse, si agrupas cada sección para que pagine todo junto de forma ordenada, en distintas páginas pueden sacarse varios reportes distintos que en si no lo son, simplemente estan juntos en uno. No es problema de código, si no del IDE a la hora de montarlo.

Comment: Podrías explicarte un poco mas por favor.

Comment: Hay maneras de paginar y agrupar los datos, los cuales pueden hacerse salir en el reporte todos ordenados gracias a las funciones del asistente, tienes que estar seguro de cargar todos los dataset que vayas a necesitar, y con el asistente de CristalReports puedes hacerlo.